# Eliminar un producto seleccionado varias veces con el mismo ID

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Resulta que estoy creando un carrito de compras con php, pero me di cuenta de que si selecciono el mismo producto 2 o más veces y voy a eliminar uno, todos los productos con la misma ID se eliminan, no sé cómo para resolver ese error.

```
        case "Eliminar":
        if (is_numeric( openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {

            $ID=openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);

            foreach ($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $producto) {
                if ($producto['ID']==$ID) {
                    unset($_SESSION['CARRITO'][$indice]);
                    echo "<script> alert ('Elemento Borrado...'); </script>";
                }

            }
        }
        else{
            //$mensaje.="Upss... ID incorrecto".$ID."</br>";
        }

        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias eso pasa porque lo estas haciendo dentro de un forechach, puedes intentar quitando el foreach, algo asi:

```
case "Eliminar":
        if (is_numeric( openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {
            $ID=openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);
            $id = $_SESSION['CARRITO'],['ID'];
            if ($producto['ID']==$ID) {
               unset($_SESSION['CARRITO'][$id]);
               echo "<script> alert ('Elemento Borrado...'); </script>";
            }
        else{
            //$mensaje.="Upss... ID incorrecto".$ID."</br>";
        }

        break;
}
```

Esto te debería funcionar!

Comment: $id = $_SESSION['CARRITO'],['ID'];  Esta linea de código genera error.